# Change the directory name of my templates tags and filters

Tags: django, django-templates

The Django specification say that:

> The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as models.py, views.py, etc.

It is really necessary do that in this exactly way?
I'll want to change the directory name of my template tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the answer is "yes, it's necessary". It's probably a good idea anyway to keep the structure as close to possible to the normal Django structure.

There's a way to add new template folders through the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` property in [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#template-dirs), but I'm not seeing anything similar for template tags.

I looked through the [django.templatetags](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/templatetags) source code but didn't see anything similar to the django.template.loader, which is what allows the functionality to change your template folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Confirmed. The name "templatetags" is hardcoded inside the function that retrieves the templatetags modules, as you can see from the Django [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/base.py#L1335).

The only alternative that I see for you is to modify the Django core code, if you are brave enough :P (no, seriously, don't do it...)